# Background sync task for react-native application is not working

Tags: react-native

In my app I want to implement backgroud file sync to the database using react-native-background-task. It is working for IOS but not working for android. Can anyone give some solution which will work for both IOS and android

Answer (score 0):

No, it just doesn't work well. I have been trying since 4 month and searching info I reach to the fact that just is a feature that is not well implemented in React-Native.